# Edit access modifier of everything in a NSView

Tags: swift, nsview

In my application I want to change the editable var at once for 3 nstextfields in a custom NSView. Is it possible to do that using only one line of code (turning something on and of in the NSView perhaps?) or do I have to change it for every object individually? Again all the nstextfields are 'grouped' in one NSView. Hiding the nsview is no option, because it will seem like the entire program is nearly empty.

I have (for example) 3 NSTextFields in a custom NSView and I want to change their edibility option for all of them at once (if that is possible). So that I don't have to do: 'textfield1.editable=false' three times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cocoa Bindings:

- Create a dynamic variable `editable` in the target class

  ```
  dynamic var editable = true
  ```
- In Interface Builder bind `Editable` of each text field to the target class , Model Key Path `editable.`

Now changing the value of the variable affects all text fields simultaneously.